# Magento categories output trouble

Tags: php, magento, categories

I create a cms page. Put in content field this line:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/category/list.phtml"}}
```

Then created `list.phtm` with code:

```
<?php

$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$collection = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);

foreach ($array as $cat) {
    echo '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
}

?>
```

But nothing happened. The file works, because if I put in some text - it displays
but categories don't . What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to loop thru `$collection`, but currently you're looping `$array`, which *is not defined* anywhere in the code you've shown.